# How can I take number input through console and pass that integer to a different class

Tags: java

I'm currently doing a project where we have to find zeroes using quadratic formuala, the point of the project is to be able to pass info through different resource classes and have different classes doing things (calculating, printing..)

I have my first class which is responsible for getting the coefficients A, B, C and returning them to a driver class.

my problem is that I don't know how to take input in the console and be able to return that as an integer.

I have java.util.Scanner ready but I'm not sure how you can return an integer from that.

Comment: `scanner.nextInt()`?

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt take a look at the javadocs for what methods are available from a class.

Javadocs for `Scanner` - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Something like:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int numberFromConsole = scanner.nextInt();
```

Will read an integer from the console into `numberFromConsole`.

If you want to read a double or long, the corresponding `Scanner` methods are `scanner.nextDouble()` and `scanner.nextLong()`.

Hope this helped!

Comment: How would I go about returning that value to a different class? I have 3 int (A, B, C) and I need to pass along the information taken from console to the driver class

Comment: You could pass the numbers you need to the constructor of the driver class. Or you could pass those values to the methods you need them for in the driver class.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant by passing a value to another class instead of "returning the value to another class". You can receive`a`, `b` & `c` using Scanner from user input:

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
int a = scn.nexInt();
```

To pass a value to an object, just create a setter for the class, and pass the value via the setter:

```
class Equation{

    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int c;

    public Equation(int a, int b, int c){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void setValues(int a, int b, int c){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
Equation equation = new Equation(a, b, c);  //you can pass directly into the constructor
```

Or pass via the setter:

```
Equation equation = new Equation();         //need a default constructor for this
equaltion.setValues(a, b, c);
```